# @378bf509 - ошибка в Java компиляторе

Tags: java

Это мой код: ↓
Первый класс:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Math m = new Math();
        m.mult(10, 10);
        System.out.println(m);
    }
}
```

Второй класс:

```
public class Math {
    public int mult (int a, int b) {
        return a * b;
    }
}
```

В консоле я получаю это - **com.company.Math@378bf509**, мне нужна помощь ...

Comment: Это сайт на русском, поэтому перепишите вопрос на русском, чтобы его не закрыли

Comment: `com.company.Math@378bf509` это не ошибка, а текстовое представление объекта, тут и его класс написан и адрес, вы сами его вывели в `System.out.println(m);`. Вообще, вы наверное хотели результат `mult` вывести, поэтому должно было быть: `System.out.println(m.mult(10, 10));`

Comment: [Джефф Дин компилирует и запускает свой код перед коммитом, но только чтобы проверить на баги компилятор и CPU](https://habr.com/ru/post/192604/) :)

Answer (score 1):

ты пишешь не правильный код:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Math m = new Math();
        m.mult(10, 10);
        System.out.println(m);
    }
}
```

в этой строке "System.out.println(m)" ты выводишь не переменную которая имеет значения результата а представление объекта то есть как он написан в тексте тебе надо выводить переменную ,поэтому код должен быть таким

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Math m = new Math();
        // забыл задать значение переменной!
        int res = m.mult(10, 10);
        // вывод ИМЕННО ПЕРЕМЕННОЙ а не объекта!
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```